# ¿Como cambiar el nombre a esta etiqueta que aparece en la pestaña de la página?

Tags: wordpress-theme

Como se puede cambiar la leyenda en la etiqueta que aparece al colocar el cursosr sobre la pestaña en la página. Usando plantilla Wordpress

[image: En Wordpress]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es la página inicial, teniendo sesión iniciada en Wordpress lo puedes cambiar yendo a:

```
Escritorio -> Ajustes -> Generales
```

y allí cambias el valor:

```
Título del sitio
```

y luego pulsas el botón

```
Guardar cambios
```

Si es una página o post, ese valor se establece editando la página o post, indicándolo en la etiqueta

```
Título o Title
```

un formato estándar para titular nuestras páginas o posts es el siguiente:

```
Título de la página o post | midominio.com
```

sabiendo que el SEO admite en ese espacio solamente 70 caracteres, los caracteres sobrantes son ignorados y para fines de SEO no conviene tener palabras que sean cortadas.

Cuando ves el código fuente de la página verás una etiqueta parecida a esta:

```
<title>Comentarios, homilías Mt 13, 47-53: ¿Quién es este? | deiverbum.org</title>
```

Cuando usas frameworks como Thesis, Génesis u otros, en la edición de páginas / posts el framework te va indicando, *para que no te pases*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las indicaciones en inglés dicen que *los buscadores permiten un máximo de 70 caracteres para el título* y el número de la izquierda: `67` indica que estoy bien, que en ese sentido mi título cumple con esa regla del SEO.

Hay plugins SEO que te ayudan también en eso. Aunque sabiendo que el límite es 70 no hay problema, cualquier editor de texto plano te cuenta los caracteres. De hecho, yo escribo mi contenido siempre en un editor de texto plano y ahí voy controlando el contenido del título.

De ese modo, cuando alguien busca y encuentra tu página en cualquier buscador, el Título no aparece cortado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias. Una pregunta. ¿Tarda el plugin SEO en ubicar la pagina y el cambio en la etiqueta?

Comment: De nada. Eso no lo hace el plugin, lo hace **cada motor de búsqueda** (Google, Bing, Yahoo...). A veces tarda su tiempo, pero si quieres acelerar el proceso puedes pedir a Google que te reindexe la página de nuevo a través de [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=es) mejor conocido como Google Webmasters Tools.

Comment: Gracias saludos